# testFunction( (string) $variable); - What is this called?

Tags: php, casting

I've seen some code written like this, and I'm really curious what it does and what it's for. Sorry for the unclear title, I appreciate all answers!

Edit: In particular I'm curious about the `(string) $variable` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

> Type casting in PHP works much as it does in C: the name of the desired type is written in parentheses before the variable which is to be cast.

```
<?php
$foo = 10;   // $foo is an integer
$bar = (boolean) $foo;   // $bar is a boolean
?>
The casts allowed are:

(int), (integer) - cast to integer
(bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
(float), (double), (real) - cast to float
(string) - cast to string
(array) - cast to array
(object) - cast to object
(unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5)
```

In your specific example a variable was being cast to a string before being passed as a parameter to `testFunction()`

Comment: Awesome thanks! I tried searching in google for a long while, but when you don't know exactly what to search, it's difficult to find. I'll accept this as the answer once the wait window is up.

Answer (score 0):

It is a function call with an argument. In this case, a variable `$variable` has been cast to a string for the argument.